# I did get object Property on UI

Tags: javascript, html, angular, find

This is my component file, when I show event object property it is not showing any on UI. somebody get their time to resolve the issue as I am a newbie into angular and project in the production.

```
 import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
            import { EventService } from '../shared/event.service';
            @Component({
              templateUrl: '../event-details/event-details.component.html',
              styles: [
                `
                  .container {
                    padding-left: 20px;
                    padding-right: 20px;
                  }
                  .event-image {
                    height: 100px;
                  }
                `
              ],
            })
            export class EventDetailsComponent implements OnInit{
              event: any;
              constructor(private eventService: EventService) {}
              ngOnInit() {
               this.event= this.eventService.getEvent(1);          
   }
            }
```

//this is my view file,where we use event property

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-11">
        <h2>{{event?.name}} </h2>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div><strong>Date:</strong> {{event?.date}}</div>
        <div><strong>Time:</strong> {{event?.time}}</div>
        <div><strong>Price:</strong> ${{event?.price}}</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <address>
          <strong>Address:</strong><br />
          {{event?.location?.address}}<br />
          {{event?.location?.city}}, {{event?.location?.country}}
        </address>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

//this my service file, where I created get event method

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class EventService {
  getEvents() {
    return EVENTS;
  }
  getEvent(id: number):any {
    return EVENTS.find((event) =>{ event.id == id,
        console.log(event)
    });

  }
}
const EVENTS = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Angular Connect',
    date: '9/26/2036',
    time: '10:00 am',
    price: 599.99,
    imageUrl: '/assets/images/angularconnect-shield.png',
    location: {
      address: '1057 DT',
      city: 'London',
      country: 'England',
    },
    sessions: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Using Angular 4 Pipes',
        presenter: 'Peter Bacon Darwin',
        duration: 1,
        level: 'Intermediate',
        abstract: `Learn all about the new pipes in Angular 4, both 
              how to write them, and how to get the new AI CLI to write 
              them for you. Given by the famous PBD, president of Angular 
              University (formerly Oxford University)`,
        voters: ['bradgreen', 'igorminar', 'martinfowler'],
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Getting the most out of your dev team',
        presenter: 'Jeff Cross',
        duration: 1,
        level: 'Intermediate',
        abstract: `We all know that our dev teams work hard, but with 
              the right management they can be even more productive, without 
              overworking them. In this session I'll show you how to get the 
              best results from the talent you already have on staff.`,
        voters: ['johnpapa', 'bradgreen', 'igorminar', 'martinfowler'],
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Angular 4 Performance Metrics',
        presenter: 'Rob Wormald',
        duration: 2,
        level: 'Advanced',
        abstract: `Angular 4 Performance is hot. In this session, we'll see 
              how Angular gets such great performance by preloading data on 
              your users devices before they even hit your site using the 
              new predictive algorithms and thought reading software 
              built into Angular 4.`,
        voters: [],
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Angular 5 Look Ahead',
        presenter: 'Brad Green',
        duration: 2,
        level: 'Advanced',
        abstract: `Even though Angular 5 is still 6 years away, we all want 
              to know all about it so that we can spend endless hours in meetings 
              debating if we should use Angular 4 or not. This talk will look at 
              Angular 6 even though no code has yet been written for it. We'll 
              look at what it might do, and how to convince your manager to 
              hold off on any new apps until it's released`,
        voters: [],
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        name: 'Basics of Angular 4',
        presenter: 'John Papa',
        duration: 2,
        level: 'Beginner',
        abstract: `It's time to learn the basics of Angular 4. This talk 
              will give you everything you need to know about Angular 4 to 
              get started with it today and be building UI's for your self 
              driving cars and butler-bots in no time.`,
        voters: ['bradgreen', 'igorminar'],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'ng-nl',
    date: '4/15/2037',
    time: '9:00 am',
    price: 950.0,
    imageUrl: '/assets/images/ng-nl.png',
    location: {
      address: 'The NG-NL Convention Center & Scuba Shop',
      city: 'Amsterdam',
      country: 'Netherlands',
    },
    sessions: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Testing Angular 4 Workshop',
        presenter: 'Pascal Precht & Christoph Bergdorf',
        duration: 4,
        level: 'Beginner',
        abstract: `In this 6 hour workshop you will learn not only how to test Angular 4, 
              you will also learn how to make the most of your team's efforts. Other topics
              will be convincing your manager that testing is a good idea, and using the new
              protractor tool for end to end testing.`,
        voters: ['bradgreen', 'igorminar'],
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Angular 4 and Firebase',
        presenter: 'David East',
        duration: 3,
        level: 'Intermediate',
        abstract: `In this workshop, David East will show you how to use Angular with the new
              ultra-real-time 5D Firebase back end, hosting platform, and wine recommendation engine.`,
        voters: ['bradgreen', 'igorminar', 'johnpapa'],
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Reading the Angular 4 Source',
        presenter: 'Patrick Stapleton',
        duration: 2,
        level: 'Intermediate',
        abstract: `Angular 4's source code may be over 25 million lines of code, but it's really 
              a lot easier to read and understand then you may think. Patrick Stapleton will talk
              about his secretes for keeping up with the changes, and navigating around the code.`,
        voters: ['martinfowler'],
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Hail to the Lukas',
        presenter: 'Lukas Ruebbelke',
        duration: 1,
        level: 'Beginner',
        abstract: `In this session, Lukas will present the 
              secret to being awesome, and how he became the President 
              of the United States through his amazing programming skills, 
              showing how you too can be success with just attitude.`,
        voters: ['bradgreen'],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'ng-conf 2037',
    date: '5/4/2037',
    time: '9:00 am',
    price: 759.0,
    imageUrl: '/assets/images/ng-conf.png',
    location: {
      address: 'The Palatial America Hotel',
      city: 'Salt Lake City',
      country: 'USA',
    },
    sessions: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'How Elm Powers Angular 4',
        presenter: 'Murphy Randle',
        duration: 2,
        level: 'Intermediate',
        abstract: `We all know that Angular is written in Elm, but did you
              know how the source code is really written? In this exciting look
              into the internals of Angular 4, we'll see exactly how Elm powers
              the framework, and what you can do to take advantage of this knowledge.`,
        voters: ['bradgreen', 'martinfowler', 'igorminar'],
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Angular and React together',
        presenter: 'Jamison Dance',
        duration: 2,
        level: 'Intermediate',
        abstract: `React v449.6 has just been released. Let's see how to use 
              this new version with Angular to create even more impressive applications.`,
        voters: ['bradgreen', 'martinfowler'],
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Redux Woes',
        presenter: 'Rob Wormald',
        duration: 1,
        level: 'Intermediate',
        abstract: `Everyone is using Redux for everything from Angular to React to 
              Excel macros, but you're still having trouble grasping it? We'll take a look
              at how farmers use Redux when harvesting grain as a great introduction to 
              this game changing technology.`,
        voters: ['bradgreen', 'martinfowler', 'johnpapa'],
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'ng-wat again!!',
        presenter: 'Shai Reznik',
        duration: 1,
        level: 'Beginner',
        abstract: `Let's take a look at some of the stranger pieces of Angular 4,
              including neural net nets, Android in Androids, and using pipes with actual pipes.`,
        voters: ['bradgreen', 'martinfowler', 'igorminar', 'johnpapa'],
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        name: 'Dressed for Success',
        presenter: 'Ward Bell',
        duration: 2,
        level: 'Beginner',
        abstract: `Being a developer in 2037 is about more than just writing bug-free code. 
              You also have to look the part. In this amazing expose, Ward will talk you through
              how to pick out the right clothes to make your coworkers and boss not only
              respect you, but also want to be your buddy.`,
        voters: ['bradgreen', 'martinfowler'],
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        name: "These aren't the directives you're looking for",
        presenter: 'John Papa',
        duration: 2,
        level: 'Intermediate',
        abstract: `Coinciding with the release of Star Wars Episode 18, this talk will show how
              to use directives in your Angular 4 development while drawing lessons from the new movie,
              featuring all your favorite characters like Han Solo's ghost and Darth Jar Jar.`,
        voters: ['bradgreen', 'martinfowler'],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'UN Angular Summit',
    date: '6/10/2037',
    time: '8:00 am',
    price: 800.0,
    imageUrl: '/assets/images/basic-shield.png',
    location: {
      address: 'The UN Angular Center',
      city: 'New York',
      country: 'USA',
    },
    sessions: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Diversity in Tech',
        presenter: 'Sir Dave Smith',
        duration: 2,
        level: 'Beginner',
        abstract: `Yes, we all work with cyborgs and androids and Martians, but 
              we probably don't realize that sometimes our internal biases can make it difficult for
              these well-designed coworkers to really feel at home coding alongside us. This talk will
              look at things we can do to recognize our biases and counteract them.`,
        voters: ['bradgreen', 'igorminar'],
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'World Peace and Angular',
        presenter: 'US Secretary of State Zach Galifianakis',
        duration: 2,
        level: 'Beginner',
        abstract: `Angular has been used in most of the major peace brokering that has
              happened in the last decade, but there is still much we can do to remove all
              war from the world, and Angular will be a key part of that effort.`,
        voters: ['bradgreen', 'igorminar', 'johnpapa'],
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Using Angular with Androids',
        presenter: 'Dan Wahlin',
        duration: 3,
        level: 'Advanced',
        abstract: `Androids may do everything for us now, allowing us to spend all day playing 
              the latest Destiny DLC, but we can still improve the massages they give and the handmade
              brie they make using Angular 4. This session will show you how.`,
        voters: ['igorminar', 'johnpapa'],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'ng-vegas',
    date: '2/10/2037',
    time: '9:00 am',
    price: 400.0,
    imageUrl: '/assets/images/ng-vegas.png',
    location: {
      address: 'The Excalibur',
      city: 'Las Vegas',
      country: 'USA',
    },
    sessions: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Gambling with Angular',
        presenter: 'John Papa',
        duration: 1,
        level: 'Intermediate',
        abstract: `No, this talk isn't about slot machines. We all know that 
              Angular is used in most waiter-bots and coke vending machines, but
              did you know that was also used to write the core engine in the majority
              of voting machines? This talk will look at how all presidential elections
              are now determined by Angular code.`,
        voters: ['bradgreen', 'igorminar'],
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Angular 4 in 60ish Minutes',
        presenter: 'Dan Wahlin',
        duration: 2,
        level: 'Beginner',
        abstract: `Get the skinny on Angular 4 for anyone new to this great new technology.
              Dan Wahlin will show you how you can get started with Angular in 60ish minutes, 
              guaranteed!`,
        voters: ['bradgreen', 'igorminar', 'johnpapa'],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a `console.log` in the array `find()` method isn't a good pattern. Try the following

```js
getEvent(id: number):any {
  return EVENTS.find((event) => event.id == id);
}
```

It might be helpful to remember in arrow functions

```js
getEvent(id: number):any {
  return EVENTS.find((event) => event.id == id);
}
```

is similar to writing

```js
getEvent(id: number):any {
  return EVENTS.find((event) => {   // <-- returns the element of the array based on the following boolean
    return event.id == id           // <-- returns a boolean
  });
}
```

It doesn't require a `return` statement if the curly braces are omitted.

Comment: I just finding what is the return value,

Comment: I've written some comments that explain the purpose of the return statements.

Answer (score 0):

In your EVENTS.find you should return true when It matches. You have 2 sentences there, so, the inline condition is not returning any value